# Create variable from command prompt results

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to get the PID of a process on my system.

For example: when I run the query

```
sc querex Fax
```

it returns the type, state, win32_exit code, PID, etc.  How would I get the PID and turn it into a variable so I can use it later in the batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=: " %%a IN ('sc queryex fax') DO IF "%%a"=="PID" SET /a pid=%%b

echo pid=%pid%
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple in PowerShell:

```
$service = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name='Fax'"
$service.ProcessId  # Outputs the process ID of the service
```